Ho do we set input signals with Angular component tests in cypress?
For auditId and paragraphId, I am getting Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'InputSignal'. error. In the component i have used input like this
  auditId = input.required<number>();
  paragraphId = input.required<number>();  



 cy.mount(TestComponent, {
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule],
      componentProperties: {
        auditId: 1,
        paragraphId: 1,
      },
    });

Since the input signals are not writable, how can we set them in the test? Please suggest some ideas. Thank you.

Do you have access to the ComponentRef of the tested component?

No.  I don't have access to the ComponentRef 

Looks like a thing you can raise an issue on Github, since input testing is essential in angular.
As a temporary workaround, you can just add as any to the signal(1) this makes the cypress test compile fine.
import { App } from "./main"
import { signal } from '@angular/core';

describe('App', () => {
    it('mounts', () => {
        cy.mount(App, {
            componentProperties: {
                auditId: signal(1) as any,
                paragraphId: signal(1) as any,
            }
        })
    })
})

The documentation also has a dedicated section for signals testing -  Testing Signals - Cypress Docs

I cannot use a signal because the component expects an input signal. and if i use input(1) i get: Unsupported call to the input function. This function can only be called in the initializer of a class member.

@narayannyaupane updated my answer with a workaround, the issue you found could be a feature/bug, please raise it in cypress github page, for getting their opinion
